# WPF C# Combox default value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with the set of a default value for a combobox :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbAuthentification" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#FF2BBFF0" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="cmbAuthentification_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>Windows</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>SQL Server</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

In the xmal, I have this code :

```
private void cmbAuthentification_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbAuthentification.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        txtUserID.IsEnabled = false;
        txtUserID.Clear();
        txtUserPwd.IsEnabled = false;
        txtUserPwd.Clear();
    }

    if (cmbAuthentification.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        txtUserID.IsEnabled = true;
        txtUserPwd.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

When I try to set SelectedIndex="0" in the ComboBox, I have an error at runtime :
NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: set ```SelectedIndex="0"``` in ```<ComboBox x:Name="cmbAuthentification" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#FF2BBFF0" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="cmbAuthentification_SelectionChanged">``` and you see error solved.

Comment: I think the error is due by txtUserID and txtUserPwd. At the selectionChanged of the cmb, the 2 elements is not know ?

Comment: You’d better use data binding instead of event. In that way, you can bind ComboBox.SelectedItem to a property in the View-Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the controls haven't yet been loaded when your event handler is executed for the first time.

You could check whether the value of the `IsLoaded` and hook up to the `Loaded` event if it returns `false`:

```
private void cmbAuthentification_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!cmbAuthentification.IsLoaded)
    {
        cmbAuthentification.Loaded += (ss, ee) => cmbAuthentification_SelectionChanged(sender, e);
        return;
    }

    if (cmbAuthentification.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        txtUserID.IsEnabled = false;
        txtUserID.Clear();
        txtUserPwd.IsEnabled = false;
        txtUserPwd.Clear();
    }

    if (cmbAuthentification.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        txtUserID.IsEnabled = true;
        txtUserPwd.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow ! Really thanks for that. I search a long time for that. I don't understand that code... but it works !

I'm beginner and it's hard to understand code :(